# Are there some PDF display plagins for React native expo

Tags: react-native, pdf, expo

I am working on an e-library project, where we have to display pdf books for children.
I would like to know if I can find some PDF plugins to display PDF nicely.

Answer (score 0):

I used to have the same problem and I figured out, that Android works very well with [rn-pdf-reader-js](https://github.com/xcarpentier/rn-pdf-reader-js). On the other hand, for ios [WebView component](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/webview/) is 100% sufficient to display PDF content, so I switched (depends on the platform) between the two of them.